# Unable to limit WebRTC P2P Multi-participant Receiving Bandwidth

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, p2p

I'm trying to change the Bandwidth On The Fly for WebRTC P2P Video Call by using this sample combining to my existing code which are multi-participants video call:

**Sample**: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/bandwidth/

When I look into WebRTC Internals via Chrome,

*bitsReceivedPerSecond* for **send (ssrc) (video)** has been dropped to the selected bandwidth. However, *bitsReceivedPerSecond* for **recv (ssrc) (video)** still remain unchanged. May I know how to make the bandwidth changes applies on both send and receive?

Below are my codes, it would be great if you could help to point out my mistakes, thanks in advance.

**Update 14/12/2018:** Added 1st option for receiver to the codes

**Problem:** Uncaught TypeError: receiver.getParameters is not a function

```
const bandwidthSelector = document.querySelector('select#bandwidth');

bandwidthSelector.disabled = false;

// renegotiate bandwidth on the fly.
bandwidthSelector.onchange = () => {
  bandwidthSelector.disabled = true;
  const bandwidth = bandwidthSelector.options[bandwidthSelector.selectedIndex].value;

  // In Chrome, use RTCRtpSender.setParameters to change bandwidth without
  // (local) renegotiation. Note that this will be within the envelope of
  // the initial maximum bandwidth negotiated via SDP.
  if ((adapter.browserDetails.browser === 'chrome' ||
       (adapter.browserDetails.browser === 'firefox' &&
        adapter.browserDetails.version >= 64)) &&
      'RTCRtpSender' in window &&
      'setParameters' in window.RTCRtpSender.prototype) {

        $.each(peers, function( index, value ) {
            const sender = value.getSenders()[0];
            const parameters = sender.getParameters();
            if (!parameters.encodings) {
              parameters.encodings = [{}];
            }
            if (bandwidth === 'unlimited') {
              delete parameters.encodings[0].maxBitrate;
            } else {
              parameters.encodings[0].maxBitrate = bandwidth * 1000;
            }
            sender.setParameters(parameters)
            .then(() => {
              bandwidthSelector.disabled = false;
            })
            .catch(e => console.error(e));

            /* 1st Option - Start */
            const receiver = value.getReceivers()[0];
            const recParameters = receiver.getParameters();

            if (!recParameters.encodings) {
              recParameters.encodings = [{}];
            }
            if (bandwidth === 'unlimited') {
              delete recParameters.encodings[0].maxBitrate;
            } else {
              recParameters.encodings[0].maxBitrate = bandwidth * 1000;
            }
            receiver.setParameters(recParameters)
            .then(() => {
              bandwidthSelector.disabled = false;
            })
            .catch(e => console.error(e));

            /* 1st Option - End */

            return;

        });             
  }

  // Fallback to the SDP munging with local renegotiation way of limiting
  // the bandwidth.
  function onSetSessionDescriptionError(error) {
      console.log('Failed to set session description: ' + error.toString());
    }
};

function updateBandwidthRestriction(sdp, bandwidth) {
  let modifier = 'AS';
  if (adapter.browserDetails.browser === 'firefox') {
    bandwidth = (bandwidth >>> 0) * 1000;
    modifier = 'TIAS';
  }
  if (sdp.indexOf('b=' + modifier + ':') === -1) {
    // insert b= after c= line.
    sdp = sdp.replace(/c=IN (.*)\r\n/, 'c=IN $1\r\nb=' + modifier + ':' + bandwidth + '\r\n');
  } else {
    sdp = sdp.replace(new RegExp('b=' + modifier + ':.*\r\n'), 'b=' + modifier + ':' + bandwidth + '\r\n');
  }
  return sdp;
}

function removeBandwidthRestriction(sdp) {
  return sdp.replace(/b=AS:.*\r\n/, '').replace(/b=TIAS:.*\r\n/, '');
}
```

**Update 14/12/2018:** 2nd option createOffer

**Problem:** Failed to set session description: InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: kStable

```
const bandwidthSelector = document.querySelector('select#bandwidth');

bandwidthSelector.disabled = false;

// renegotiate bandwidth on the fly.
bandwidthSelector.onchange = () => {
  bandwidthSelector.disabled = true;
  const bandwidth = bandwidthSelector.options[bandwidthSelector.selectedIndex].value;

  // In Chrome, use RTCRtpSender.setParameters to change bandwidth without
  // (local) renegotiation. Note that this will be within the envelope of
  // the initial maximum bandwidth negotiated via SDP.
  if ((adapter.browserDetails.browser === 'chrome' ||
       (adapter.browserDetails.browser === 'firefox' &&
        adapter.browserDetails.version >= 64)) &&
      'RTCRtpSender' in window &&
      'setParameters' in window.RTCRtpSender.prototype) {

        $.each(peers, function( index, value ) {
            const sender = value.getSenders()[0];
            const parameters = sender.getParameters();
            if (!parameters.encodings) {
              parameters.encodings = [{}];
            }
            if (bandwidth === 'unlimited') {
              delete parameters.encodings[0].maxBitrate;
            } else {
              parameters.encodings[0].maxBitrate = bandwidth * 1000;
            }
            sender.setParameters(parameters)
            .then(() => {
              bandwidthSelector.disabled = false;
            })
            .catch(e => console.error(e));

            /* 2nd option - Start */
            value.createOffer(
                    function (local_description) {
                        console.log("Local offer description is: ", local_description);
                        value.setLocalDescription(local_description,
                            function () {
                                signaling_socket.emit('relaySessionDescription', {
                                    'peer_id': index,
                                    'session_description': local_description
                                });
                                console.log("Offer setLocalDescription succeeded");
                            },
                            function () {
                                Alert("Offer setLocalDescription failed!");
                            }
                        );
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        console.log("Error sending offer: ", error);
                    }).then(() => {
                  const desc = {
                    type: value.remoteDescription.type,
                    sdp: bandwidth === 'unlimited'
                      ? removeBandwidthRestriction(value.remoteDescription.sdp)
                      : updateBandwidthRestriction(value.remoteDescription.sdp, bandwidth)
                  };
                  console.log('Applying bandwidth restriction to setRemoteDescription:\n' +
                    desc.sdp);
                  return value.setRemoteDescription(desc);
                })
                .then(() => {
                  bandwidthSelector.disabled = false;
                })
                .catch(onSetSessionDescriptionError);

            /* 2nd option - End */

            return;

        });             
  }

  // Fallback to the SDP munging with local renegotiation way of limiting
  // the bandwidth.
  function onSetSessionDescriptionError(error) {
      console.log('Failed to set session description: ' + error.toString());
    }
};

function updateBandwidthRestriction(sdp, bandwidth) {
  let modifier = 'AS';
  if (adapter.browserDetails.browser === 'firefox') {
    bandwidth = (bandwidth >>> 0) * 1000;
    modifier = 'TIAS';
  }
  if (sdp.indexOf('b=' + modifier + ':') === -1) {
    // insert b= after c= line.
    sdp = sdp.replace(/c=IN (.*)\r\n/, 'c=IN $1\r\nb=' + modifier + ':' + bandwidth + '\r\n');
  } else {
    sdp = sdp.replace(new RegExp('b=' + modifier + ':.*\r\n'), 'b=' + modifier + ':' + bandwidth + '\r\n');
  }
  return sdp;
}

function removeBandwidthRestriction(sdp) {
  return sdp.replace(/b=AS:.*\r\n/, '').replace(/b=TIAS:.*\r\n/, '');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTCRtpSender only controls the sending bandwidth. If you want to limit the receiving bandwidth, you need to use either the b=AS / b=TIAS way or make the receiver use setParameters.

Comment: Hi @Philipp, I've tried two options, however, I'm not familiar with WebRTC, both options returned errors, may I know which option is suitable and how to make it works? I've updated the codes above with the problems together. Thank you

Comment: ah... with "receiver" I meant the party receiving the call, not the RTCRtpReceiver. Terminology is tricky.
The "called in wrong state" error is probably due to using onnegotiationeeded. There are several questions on stackoverflow about that.

Comment: Hi @Philipp, I finally solved this issue by sending a request to the receiver to make change on the bandwidth. Thank you so much!